# Is there a constant $k$ which $k^{4n+1}=k^{4n+2}=1, k^{4n+3}=k^{4n}=-1$?

Tags: logarithms, pi, constants

We can be sure, that
$$\log(1+i)=\frac{\pi i}{4}+\frac{\log(2)}{2}$$
then if we take
$$\log(1+k)=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\log(2)}{2}$$
so sign-alternating is $++--$.
Is there a constant $k$ which $k^{4n+1}=k^{4n+2}=1, k^{4n+3}=k^{4n}=-1$?

Comment: No. $k^{4n+1}=k^{4n+2}$ already implies that $k=0$ or $k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$k^{4n+1} = k^{4n+2}$$

just means either $k = 0$ or $k = 1$...